# Authentication using end points in ADFS 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, adfs, adfs3.0

I had installed ADFS 3.0 in my server. Where should I configure the authorize, token and user info endpoint in server. I could not find out a good article on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about *OpenID Connect* or *OAuth2*?

The only available endpoints are under: *AD FS > Service > Endpoints*.

There is only one: */adfs/oauth2/*

Comment: I have the endpoint information and will post it here soon for others to refer to, so they do not run into issues that I encounter

Comment: I donot find an end point to which i can post the access token and get back the user profile in adfs 3

Comment: I have a sequence of steps posted in a blog post https://dsaravanan.wordpress.com/2014/12/12/configuring-ad-fs-3-0-in-windows-server-2012-r2/

Comment: This is more about installing ADFS than answering the OAuth question?

Comment: I have attached the last screenshot of the code that can be used to access the AD FS 3.0 end points via code.